# How do I query this information

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I got this script  and he is me returning all tables of my database like to know how do I only see table "CITY_NAME" my DB.

I really appreciate anyone who can help me

```
<?php

//Configure the MySQL conwection
$host = 'localhost';4
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'ip2location';
$table_name = 'ip2location_db3';

//Get the visitor IP address
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//In case you are testing locally with 127.0.0.1,
//you can uncomment the below line to assign the IP address
//to 8.8.8.8 (or whatever) for your testing.
$ip = '8.8.8.8';

try{
    //Create and perform the SQL query using the PDO
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database . ';charset=utf8', $user, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $st = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `' . $table_name . '` WHERE INET_ATON(:ip) <= ip_to LIMIT 1');
    $st->execute(array(':ip'=>$ip));

    $row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



    //Print out the result
    var_dump($row);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

Comment: I suggests you start reading a basic introduction into the sql language. Then you can easily answer your question yourself.

Comment: `CITY_NAME` is a table name or column name of your table

Comment: You're right. It was column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you want to view only `city_name` column from your table. Just use `city_name` instead of `*` in select query like below. SQL101

```
'SELECT city_name FROM `' . $table_name . '` WHERE INET_ATON(:ip) <= ip_to LIMIT 1'
```